# Why std::map::emplace_hint's time complexity is constant providing correct hint

Tags: c++, stl

From cppreference, it is said the complexity of [std::map::emplace_hint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint) is:

```
Complexity
Logarithmic in the size of the container in general, but amortized constant if the new element is inserted just before hint.
```

Why it is constant if we provide a good hint?

Comment: You trying to make a documentation?

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` is a red-black tree, in order to insert/emplace an new element into a `std::map`, we need:

1. Find the proper position to insert/emplace the new element - O(lgN)
2. Recolor and rotate nodes to keep red-black tree properties. - O(1)

If a good hint is provided,  the search part(#1) is already done, and for #2 there are [4 scenarios](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IBxA-bZZH8), with each of them O(1)

So with proper hint, `std::map::emplace_hint` is O(1)

Comment: nitpick: `std::map` is not specified to be a red-black tree, although that is a common implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse my limited knowledge on the subject here.

> If a good hint is provided, the search part(#1) is already done.
> Blockquote

The container shall consume O(logN) for finding the node==hint right?
In that case total time complexity becomes -> #1 O(logN) + #2 O(1) = O(logN)